# Aside from Feature Extraction, can t-SNE do feature selection?

Tags: pca, feature-selection, tsne

I am working on a genomics project, that contains a dataset of ~100 cells (that contains 8 classes of cells) and ~20,000 genes. I am interested in trying to find out what genes are influential in classifying the 8 cell types, but am challenged by the curse of dimensionality.

After doing some research, it seems that researchers have used PCA and t-SNE to tackle similar challenges. I understand that for PCA, one can examine the loadings of the PCs to determine which genes are influential. However, I haven't read anything of a similar procedure for t-SNE. Is there a way to examine which genes are influential by using t-SNE (feature selection), or is t-SNE only capable of doing feature extraction?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It would not belong on [SO]. It is on topic here. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: No. There is no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

t-SNE is mostly used to visualize high dimensional data by embedding it in a 2D space. Since it ignores the classes, it can't tell you which variables are important for classification.

PCA also ignores the classes, so although it can tell you which variables explain the variance of the data, that might not be the same as which variables best distinguish the classes.

Linear Discriminant does include the classes so may be more useful.